# My Discord bot ist not responding (javascript)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I am trying to code my own Discord Bot when I start it with node. It does but when I then type `*ping` it's not responding as it should

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '*';


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Testbot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(" ");
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
});
```

Where is the error?

Comment: If you try logging `args` and `command`, what do you get?

Comment: `console.log(args)` under `const args` and the same with `command` (`console.log(command)`). Check the output in the console

Comment: Also you can try logging `message`

Comment: You misspelled `length` as `lenght`.

Comment: In the line `const args...`, there is a typo: `prefix.lenght` should be `prefix.length`

Comment: i fixed the typo and when i send *ping in discord in the console it logs [ '*ping' ] *ping

Comment: nevermind i restartet and now it work    thank you very much!

Comment: That makes sense. I was wondering why it didn't work after the change because it does in this bad mockup: https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/WhimsicalOnerlookedGraduate#index.js

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you spelled `length` as `lenght`

This would have probably caused an error in your console. Next time please upload the error as well.

Also, since you are copying code off the discord.js guide anyways, why don't you check with those first?